# Question concering Lebesgue measure of a set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $c$ is a constant, and $f : A \rightarrow [ 0 , \infty ] $ is lebesgue measureable. Prove the following, where $\mu$ denotes Lebesgue measure.
$$ \mu\left( \{ x \in A \mid f(x) \geq c \} \right) \leq \frac{1}{c} \int_A f \, d\mu $$

Currently not sure how to approach this.

Comment: This is Tschebyshev's inequality. Consider $\|f\|=\int_{|f|\ge c}|f|+\int_{|f|<c}|f|$, and make some inequalities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that from linearity of Lebesgue integrals we have
$$c \cdot \mu\left( \{ x \in A \mid f(x) \geq c \}\right)=c\cdot \int_B 1\; d\mu =\int_B c\; d\mu \leq \int_B f(x) \; d\mu \leq \int_A f(x)\; d\mu$$
Where $B = \{ x\in A |\;  f(x)\geq c\}\subset A$